# Integrate Extent Reports with AWS Device Farm and Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

I am new to automation and I have been integrating **AWS device farm** to run my test cases on cloud. I have **integrated Jenkins with AWS device farm** to run the tests on the go. I want to integrate **Extent Reports** to see the results of the run inside Jenkins. I can't find any tutorial to do so. Can you please help me with this.

I have installed the HTML publisher in Jenkins and I have implemented Extent Reports for my local run and its working. But, I have no idea how to integrate for the cloud.

Thanks in advance. Stay Safe

Here is my code for local integration of Extent Reports

```
    ExtentTest test;
    ExtentReports extent = ExtentReportsBlackstone.getReportObject();
    ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> extentTest = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
    AppiumDriver<?> driver ;
    
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName()).assignCategory(result.getMethod().getGroups());
        extentTest.set(test);
    }
    
    @Override       
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result){                  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        extentTest.get().log(Status.PASS, "Test Passed");
        Properties prop = UtilityBase.globalProperties();
        if(prop.getProperty("captureScreenshotOnTestPass").equals("true")) {
            String testMethodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
            try {
                    Class clazz = result.getTestClass().getRealClass();
                    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("driver");   
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    driver = (AppiumDriver<?>) field.get(result.getInstance());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                extentTest.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenshot(this.driver,testMethodName), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }   
    
    @Override       
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {                 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        extentTest.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        
        String testMethodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        try {
                Class clazz = result.getTestClass().getRealClass();
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("driver");   
                field.setAccessible(true);
                driver = (AppiumDriver<?>) field.get(result.getInstance());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            extentTest.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenshot(this.driver,testMethodName), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }   
    
     @Override      
     public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {                  
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
                    
    }
    
    @Override       
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {                  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                
    }       
    
    @Override       
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {                 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        try {
            UtilityBase.deleteFolder(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/reports");
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }       

    
    @Override       
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {                    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        extent.flush();
    }       


}
```

Answer (score 0):

estimate cannot be integrated, aws is a bit limited and for that option we opted for lambatest, where we send it to run in the cloud but the evidence remains in extend report in our aws node

aws asks to compile the project and upload the project which runs on its own server, I don't like that way of execution